# Question for Rocket Science

Tags: science-in-society

Could a nuclear fission rocket engine ever work?

Do you think it could work better than rocket fuel?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Naeeem! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods. Have fun!

Comment: What kind? Have a look at the [Atomic Rockets blog](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE, Naeeem!  Stack Exchange invites its users to perform basic research before asking questions on its site.  What research have you performed?  Why do you believe fission engines might not work?

Comment: @FoxElemental, Whoops!

Comment: I could write an essay or post a video... [Here's the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aBOhC1c6m8)

Comment: This question is better for https://space.stackexchange.com/ where you will likely get Ash's comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can fission be harnessed for spaceflight? Most certainly **yes**. But what you get depends on what you want it for:

There are designs for bomb driven spacecraft: Daedalus, Orion, Medusa & Longshot to name the most known ones. Use one in the atmosphere? **NO** by far!

Then there are Nuclear Reactors that heat the gas used for moving. We call them "Nuclear thermal rocket" and a few of them actually have been tested. The [NERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA) progam is one of them: they fired the KIWI and Pewee reactor/engines under the codename Phoebus. That's also *not nice* in the atmosphere. And they are heavy, even if efficient. and there is a minimum size the reactor needs to function at all, limiting them to being used for large engines.

You want to know more?! There is Project rho, who have [a long article on this stuff.](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/engines.php) [And another.](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php) Russia claims they [run a nuclear-driven cruise missile](https://www.armscontrolwonk.com/archive/1205006/russias-nuclear-powered-cruise-missile/). USAF did scrap their [Project Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Pluto). And all in all: please read [the wiki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_in_space)

Are they better than normal rockets? Depends on what you want to use them for and what kind of design.

Comment: They are better for propulsion in space by pretty much any standard. For takeoff from the ground? Not so much. (They tend to have inelegantly radioactive exhaust.)

Comment: @MarkOlson depends on WHAT is your measurement against: they can't be amde below a certain size and they are heavy. Which limits their usability.

Comment: Yah, sure, but I'm pretty sure that wasn't what the OP meant.